# How can I remove the bright glare regions in image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have some tomato images with bright shadow on tomatoes. I want to remove/reduce these bright shadow points. Is there any suggestion?

[image]

I tried below code but It did not solve my problem:

```
def decrease_brightness(img, value=30):
  hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
  h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)

  lim = 255 - value
  v[v >= lim] -= value

  final_hsv = cv2.merge((h, s, v))
  img = cv2.cvtColor(final_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
  return img

image = decrease_brightness(image, value=50)
```

Comment: Can you tell the reason why those codes don't solve your issue? and also please add a `python` tag on your question since you're using `python` programing language

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The bright shadow parts are not reduced or removed after using decrease brightness code.

Comment: Make a mask of the bright regions by thresholding (cv2.inRange). Then use inpainting to remove the bright regions and fill them in with tomato texture. Both OpenCV and SkImage have inpainting methods.

Comment: @fmw42 Could you share the code of this processing?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how to do the inpainting in Python/OpenCV.

*Note that shadows are dark. You want to remove the bright glare regions. Please use the correct terms so that you do not confuse others on the forum. Refer to a dictionary.*

- Read the input
- Threshold on the gray background using cv2.inRange()
- Apply morphology to close and dilate
- Floodfill the outside with black to make a mask image
- Use the mask to do the inpainting (two methods)
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('tomato.jpg')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# threshold
lower = (150,150,150)
upper = (240,240,240)
thresh = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

# apply morphology close and open to make mask
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (25,25))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, iterations=1)

# floodfill the outside with black
black = np.zeros([hh + 2, ww + 2], np.uint8)
mask = morph.copy()
mask = cv2.floodFill(mask, black, (0,0), 0, 0, 0, flags=8)[1]

# use mask with input to do inpainting
result1 = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 101, cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
result2 = cv2.inpaint(img, mask, 101, cv2.INPAINT_NS)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("tomato_thresh.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("tomato_morph.jpg", morph)
cv2.imwrite("tomato_mask.jpg", mask)
cv2.imwrite("tomato_inpaint1.jpg", result1)
cv2.imwrite("tomato_inpaint2.jpg", result2)

# display it
cv2.imshow("IMAGE", img)
cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.imshow("MORPH", morph)
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("RESULT1", result1)
cv2.imshow("RESULT2", result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold Image:

[image]

Morphology and Floodfill Image:

[image]

Mask Image:

[image]

Inpaint Telea:

[image]

Inpaint Navier-Stokes:

[image]